# SQL query to find the second occurrence of an element in a database

Tags: sql, presto

For example I have this table:

```
seenID | personID | seenTime
-------+----------+---------
   108      3         13:34
   109      2         13:56
   110      3         14:22
   111      3         14:31
   112      4         15:04
   113      2         15:52
```

I want to get the row where the `PersonID` occurs for the second time.

So the desired output needs to be (for one of the person ID) :

```
seenID | personID | seenTime
-------+----------+---------
   110      3         14:22
```

What would be the query for this scenario?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far?? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i just know how to get the first and last occurrence. I group it by personID and then get the MIN and MAX of seenTime

Comment: Do you want the second row for a particular personID (i.e. one result row) or the second row per personID (i.e. many result rows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ROW_NUMBER()** Function For this scenario

Please Refer this link for how to use this function different way
[ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Query In** > *SQL Server (T-SQL)*

```
   SELECT seenID,personID,seenTime FROM 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY personID ORDER BY personID) AS row_num,* 
        FROM "YourTableName"
    )AS T
WHERE row_num = 2
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

### For one particular person

Use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`.

```
select *
from mytable
where personid = 3
order by seentime
offest 1
limit 1;
```

(From what I read, there once was a single DBMS called Presto, which was also called PrestoDB and PrestoSQL at times. This split into two different products, Presto and Trino. If you are using Trino, you can replace the proprietary `LIMIT` clause with a standard SQL `FETCH` clause.)

### Per person

Number the rows with standard SQL's analytic function `ROW_NUMBER` and keep all rows that got numbered second.

```
select seenid, personid, seentime
from
(
  select
    seenid, personid, seentime,
    row_number() over (partition by personid order by seentime) as rn
  from mytable
) numbered
where rn = 2
order by personid;
```